# Using a loop for() on a serie of variables imported from .txt files in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, import

I'm new to R and trying to optimize a script.
I have a very basic script that import data from a .txt file and after few manipulations save a boxplot of the data. 
Since I have to repeat the same script for many variables I was trying to build my first loop in R.

```
genes <- c("gene1", "gene2")
for(i in genes){
i <- read.table(file="i.txt", header=T, sep="\t")#load data from a file
i_adipose_c <- subset(i, Tissue == "adipose-cancer", select = c("Tissue", "Expression_level"))#select column needed
i_adipose_n <- subset(i, Tissue == "adipose-normal", select = c("Tissue", "Expression_level"))#select column needed
i_adipose_c <- i_adipose_c[, "adipose_c"]#change dataframe into vector of integers
i_adipose_n <- i_adipose_n[, "adipose_n"]#change dataframe into vector of integers
sq <- seq(max(length(i_adipose_c), length(i_adipose_n)))#define the max lengh of the 2 vectors
i_adipose <- data.frame(i_adipose_c[sq], i_adipose_n[sq])#merge the 2 vectors according to max length using na for missing values
png(filename="i_adipose_graph.png", res = 300, units = "px", width = 3000, height = 1600)
par(mar=c(15,5,1,1))
boxplot(i_adipose, las=2, ylab = "i Gene expression")
dev.off() 
}
```

This code retruns the following error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'i.txt': No such file or directory
```

I guess this means that my loop did not understood it has to replace "i" by the names in the genes vector.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank! (any other optimization is much welcomed!)

Comment: I edited my answer to incldue the assignment of data, let me know if it is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the variable `i` defined in your loop as a character vector in your filename.

Let me explain, when you write `for (i in genes)`, this means that each time the code will loop, `i` will be attributed a new value based on `genes`. 
In your example, `i` will become `gene1` and then `gene2`.

```r
genes = c("gene1","gene2")

> for(i in genes){print(i)}
[1] "gene1"
[1] "gene2"
```

However, when you write `file = "i.txt"`, R is looking to open a file named `i.txt`.

If you want to open a text file called `gene1.txt` and `gene2.txt`, you need to enter:
`file = paste0(i,".txt")`. So, now, R is looking for a file that is the concatenation of `i` (and so `gene1`) + `.txt` giving `gene1.txt`

```r
> for(i in genes){print(paste0(i,".txt"))}
[1] "gene1.txt"
[1] "gene2.txt"
```

So, first, you have to look for your text filename. If your text files are called `gene1.txt` and `gene2.txt`, then you can do the following with your code:

```r
genes <- c("gene1", "gene2")
for(i in genes){
  data <- read.table(file=paste0(i,".txt"), header=T, sep="\t")#load data from a file

  assign(i,data,.GlobalEnv) # See explanations at the end of the answer

  data_adipose_c <- subset(data, Tissue == "adipose-cancer", select = c("Tissue", "Expression_level"))#select column needed
  data_adipose_n <- subset(data, Tissue == "adipose-normal", select = c("Tissue", "Expression_level"))#select column needed
  data_adipose_c <- data_adipose_c[, "adipose_c"]#change dataframe into vector of integers
  data_adipose_n <- data_adipose_n[, "adipose_n"]#change dataframe into vector of integers
  sq <- seq(max(length(data_adipose_c), length(data_adipose_n)))#define the max lengh of the 2 vectors
  data_adipose <- data.frame(data_adipose_c[sq], data_adipose_n[sq])#merge the 2 vectors according to max length using na for missing values
  png(filename=paste0(i,"_adipose_graph.png"), res = 300, units = "px", width = 3000, height = 1600)
  par(mar=c(15,5,1,1))
  boxplot(i_adipose, las=2, ylab = paste0(i," Gene expression"))
  graphics.off() 
}
```

I also modify your assignment of the opened text file to i because you are looking to recycle the value of i as `gene1` or `gene2` to save your boxplot and add legend. 
When you write: `i <- read.table(file="i.txt", header=T, sep="\t")`, `i` will become the dataframe that you open (all values contained in the text file) and won't be anymore `i = gene1`.

**Assign**
Using `assign` will duplicate `data` and attribute a name defined by `i` (here `gene1` or `gene2`). Like that, your data will be in your environment under the name `gene1` or `gene2` and not replaced by the next iteration of the for loop.

Let me know if everything is not clear to you

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for thank you very much! Can I use the same paste0 trick to name the variables where you replaced "i" by "data"? I would like to keep the individual variable for each genes (in this loop, the data will be replaced in each iteration, right?)

Comment: @Sebrw, no you can't use `paste0(i,...)` to define the name of an object. And yes, the data will be replaced at each iteration of the loop. If you want to keep trace of the text file in your environment, you have to use `assign`. I'm editing my answer to reflect this change